# Shared library not found when installing samba-ad-dc with 800-171 security policy enabled

Tags: rhel, samba, shared-library, fips

In the interest of ensuring compliance I’m trying to get the Samba DC running on Rocky Linux 8 with the FIPS 800-171 security policy enabled. Fresh minimal VM install from the DVD image, I download and unzip the .tar, run the bootstrap.sh for Centos8S, `./configure` `make` `make install` the source (default settings), set up the systemd service, and try to run it; but I hit the following error:

```
Nov 30 14:26:03 171-dc-test systemd[1]: Starting Samba Active Directory Domain Controller...
-- Subject: Unit samba-ad-dc.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit samba-ad-dc.service has begun starting up.
Nov 30 14:26:03 171-dc-test samba[1449]: /usr/local/samba/sbin/samba: error while loading shared libraries: libevents-samba4.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Nov 30 14:26:03 171-dc-test systemd[1]: samba-ad-dc.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=127
Nov 30 14:26:03 171-dc-test systemd[1]: samba-ad-dc.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
-- Subject: Unit failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- The unit samba-ad-dc.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 30 14:26:03 171-dc-test systemd[1]: Failed to start Samba Active Directory Domain Controller.
-- Subject: Unit samba-ad-dc.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit samba-ad-dc.service has failed.
--
-- The result is failed.
```

The file in question is located exactly where it should be:

```
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 8192 Nov 30 14:09 /usr/local/samba/lib/private/libevents-samba4.so
```

Performing this exact procedure on another VM with no security policy enabled works perfectly. Setting `selinux` to permissive, stopping `fapolicyd`, and disabling FIPS mode & rebooting does not affect the results. Anybody know where I need to look to find out why this isn’t working? I’m assuming something is blocking access to that folder but I’m not sure what it would be. Thanks.